# How to include a shared asset folder between android projects?

Tags: android, resources, android-assets, shared-directory

Let's say that I have 2 projects with that use the same images.

**All** pictures are stored in folders:

```
/pictures/set1/
/pictures/set2/
/pictures/set3/
/pictures/set4/
/pictures/set5/
```

**Project 1** needs:

```
/assets/pictures/set1/
/assets/pictures/set5/
```

**Project 2** needs:

```
/assets/pictures/set2/
/assets/pictures/set5/
```

*Currently*: I copy all images to the /assets/ folder. This *duplicates my images,* and is more difficult to manage after upgrading the images.

**Is there a way I can share those images, and only build my app with the resources I need?**
This without including them in both projects manually?

Comment: see SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can share those images?

yes, put all your images into the asset folder under one project and drag the folder onto "asset" folder name in the other project in eclipse. and click "link to files and folders" if you are asked to make a choice.

> only build my app with the resources I need

if you use [Proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html), it will remove all resources and functions(and lots of stuff) that aren't used in your project